# How to play a lots of sound effects?

Tags: java, audio

I'm trying to make a rhythm game, and when the player hits the note in the right time, it should play a hit sound, and there's sometimes a lots of fast notes.

I tried three ways of doing that, but each one had a problem.

**First:** I tried to use `AudioClip` class from `JavaFX`, since I'm using it to play the music... It works, but sometimes it plays the sound too late, and when played too much, it stops playing sound and crashes the application after a few seconds.

**Second:** After that, I found the `AudioClip` from the `java.applet`, creating it through `Applet.newAudioClip(URL url)`, it works, but sometimes it doesn't play.

**Third:** I tried to use `Clip`, wich had the same effect of applet's `AudioClip`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the [JavaFX AudioClip class in Java 8](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/media/AudioClip.html) and see if that solves the JavaFX AudioClip playback issues you reported (it should).

**Regarding JavaFX AudioClip Crashes**

There was an issue with JavaFX in Java 7: [RT-35851 JVM crash playing AudioClip](https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-35851).

In the comments on RT-35851 the developer says:

> On my Windows 7 machine I can reproduce the bug on JDK 7u45 (FX 2.2.45) and 7u51 (FX 2.2.51). I get an intermittent crash with no stack trace. When this happens, the JVM restarts . . . I left the app running on JDK 8 for almost 2 hours (70,000 iterations) with no problem. So this bug is specific to JDK 7 / FX 2.

**Regarding JavaFX AudioClip Playback Timing**

> sometimes it plays the sound too late

I experienced this issue with the JavaFX AudioClip too, but only the very first time I played the AudioClip.  As a work-around, what I did was play clips for each of my clip media files with a volume set at zero at application start-up, then set the clip volume back to normal before trying to play them when I really needed them.  After I did that, the clips seemed to play immediately.  Not sure if that workaround is still necessary with Java 8 or not.

There was also an issue filed in the JavaFX issue tracker: [RT-24912 delayed audio playback on AudioClip](https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-24912).  RT-24912 is marked as fixed for "Lombard", which was the codename for JavaFX development for Java 8, so the fix should for this issue should be in Java 8.

In the comments on RT-24912, the developer says:

> I found the root cause of this and am testing a fix. I've not been able to reproduce either the delay or the crash I was experiencing with the fix so far . . . No longer reproducible with the fix for RT-25063 (tested on Windows 7 and Mac OS X) so I'm resolving this.

**Regarding the Number of Simultaneous Playable JavaFX AudioClips**

In the comments on RT-24912, the developer notes:

> Each underlying implementation can only handle a finite number of simultaneously playing clips (actual number is undefined) and the priority is used to determine which clips will be played when that number is exceeded. If you don't hit that limit then it has no effect.

---

If you have further issues with JavaFX AudioClips, create a small reproducible code sample, then log a bug with the code sample and an environment description to https://javafx-jira.kenai.com.

Answer (score 0):

This might help

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/sound/

"Whereas sampled audio is a direct representation of a sound itself, MIDI data can be thought of as a recipe for creating a sound, especially a musical sound."

Comment: Why do you think that MIDI will work for the original poster? He doesn't appear to be trying to create music but rather game sounds.

Comment: But if i understand his post correctly, he says that he want to play lots of sound effects.

Comment: MIDI is just "information", it does not directly relate to playing actual audio samples. 
Think of MIDI like "instructions"... MIDI carries just data about the sound to be played, but not the sound itself... it can carry the Volume, Pan, Velocity, Note... but the "receiver"(MIDI Input) is the one responsible to translate that signal and play the actual sound... but still, the "receiver" was the responsible to implement the sound. The same signal can be implemented for different sounds... My problem is actually playing a sound, lots of times, with accurate timing.